# Impossible to find "select" element with selenium even though it is there in source

Tags: select, selenium, testing

Can someone please tell me what is the selector I have to use to choose the select element below? (code below) I tried below thing but am not able to choose the select element.

> I used ".input-box .cp-select-box select" as selector, but selenium returns element not found. I don't understand why!
>
> I then tried "#billing:prefix" as selector, but selenium returns element not found. I don't understand why!
>
> I then tried "select[name=billing[prefix]]" as selector, but selenium returns element not found. I don't understand why!
>
> I then tried "select[title=Title]" as selector, but selenium returns element not found. I don't understand why!

I want to use this selector in this code to choose a value:-- $this->select($this->byCssSelector($selector for select))->selectOptionByValue("Mr");

```
<div class="input-box validation-error">
    <div class="cp-select-box">
        <select id="billing:prefix" name="billing[prefix]" title="Title" class="required-entry validation-failed" style="width: 323px; height: 38px;">
            <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
            <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
            <option value="Ms">Ms</option>
            <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
            <option value="Dr">Dr</option>
            <option value="Sir">Sir</option>
            <option value="Prof">Prof</option>
            <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
        </select><span class="default-text" style="width: 288px;"></span><div class="validation-advice" id="advice-required-entry-billing:prefix" style="">This is a required field.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can someone please tell me what is going on?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you have any iframes on the page?

Comment: I don't see any iframe tag at all. However I see loadIframe javascript function. I am bad at javascript. How can I find out now other than searching for iframe tag to see if there an iframe?

Comment: @JakeJ: What browser are you using? If its chrome, in the chrome dev tool, you can see the list of iframes loaded if any.

Comment: Thank you guys. Fixed it!! I saw that opacity for that select is set to 0 and a custom select has been added on top of it using javascript. Selenium doesn't pick it up if opacity is 0 even if css selector is correct.